# What are parameters and context in PyQGIS processAlgorithm function?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am working on a Python scripts which are used in a QGIS  module. In every script, there is the `processAlgorithm` function calling `parameters` and `context`. I can't find what are theses variables and where they are defined.

My purpose is to extract the code of theses scripts to avoid using QGIS software.

Anyone knows how can I define my own `parameters` and `context` variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find here the documentation of the QgsProcessingContext:
https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Processing/QgsProcessingContext.html

I show the desktop manual to better understand parameters:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#creating-scripts-and-running-them-from-the-toolbox

Finally you find the documentation of the QgsProcessingParameters:
https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Processing/QgsProcessingParameters.html